# Basic PHP password protected webpage

Tags: php

I am trying to figure out an easy way to have a password protected php page.

Essentially it would just have a user name and password field with one username and one password (pre set).  If entered wrong it notifies the user, if entered right it reveals the page.

I don't want to use a database and I am pretty sure can be done in a simple PHP script, thing is it's a language on my list to do.

Anyone help me out here? Thanks a lot in advanced.

Comment: If you don't want a database how would you prefer to do it? Do you want to hard code it into the page/script? Will this be one password that never changes? Some code and a little more info would help.

Comment: sorry for the vague details as pretty much any option without a database was what I was looking for...hard coded works fine and jessh provided the perfect code. To Oil, i'm sorry i didn't post the "what have I tried" as I know extremely little PHP but understand enough languages to understand PHP..I was just looking for where to start as Google only provided database answers.  So to answer your question, "Google".  Sorry again and thanks to everyone for helping.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Code here: http://pastebin.com/j16kfGD6

Comment: Another one: https://www.saudiqbal.com/blog/php-password-protect-single-page-script-with-multiple-users.php